# What about propTypes inside body of functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

The standard way of specifying propTypes for a functional component is after the function body:

```
const One = ({text}) => {
    return <div>One says {text}</div>
};

One.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default One;
```

I've seen somewhere an alterative way, with the `propTypes` attribute written inside the function body:

```
const One = ({text}) => {
    One.propTypes = {
       text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };

    return <div>One says {text}</div>
};

export default One;
```

I actually tend to prefer the second one, especially if the component has many lines, so that the propTypes (part of the contract) is visually close to the declaration.
But this way is almost nowhere mentioned, and it makes me wonder:

Is that valid ES6 ( to assign properties to an arrow function inside
the body)?  I'd though it wasn't, because the assigment of the
function to the variable `One` has not taken place at that point...
but it seems to work  - example below.

Does it have any shortcoming?

```js
const mifunc = (x,y) => {
 mifunc.prop1 = 'hi'; 
 return x+y;
}

console.log(mifunc(2,3));
console.log(mifunc.prop1);
```

Comment: The second example works because you're only declaring the function but its `propTypes` property doesn't get set until the first time it's invoked, so your assumption that the assignment hasn't taken place at that point is incorrect. Personally, I don't see any benefit to that approach. It means the component doesn't even have any `propTypes` until after it's been rendered once and it gets needlessly overwritten every time it's rendered.

Comment: @Lennholm Your comment should be an answer, I think.